# Java TelegramApiRequestException: Error getting updates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, telegram, telegram-bot

As I know this error occurs when several bot instances are running, bit I run only one instance.

I noticed that

1. There are no *"TelegramApiRequestException: Error getting updates"* errors if I create and register bot like this:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new MyBot());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But in this case autowiring doesn't work.

2. Here autowiring is working, but that *"TelegramApiRequestException: Error getting updates"* message spams my logs

```java
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    static {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyBot;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(bot);

        myService.doSomeWork();
    }
}
```

[logs img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDRAM.png)

Comment: Not much to go on, but the first snippet looks like is plain old JAVA, not starting up via Spring. So, auto-wiring would not kick in. The second is Spring based (using CommandLineRunner. The spamming part is a separate issue.

Comment: @DariusX. the first part is everywhere in telegram bot tutorials. the second one is an adapted version for Spring boot to be able to autowire services. But in the last case "TelegramApiRequestException: Error getting updates" error message occurs and it spams logs

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes across the same problem, I guess I found a solution. If you inject your bot as a dependency, you don't need to manually register it - just put your `@Component` annotation over your bot class and that's it.

If not, then you need to manually register it just like OP did in their case. I had the same problem. I didn't put `@Component` annotation at first, rather created bot bean via `@Bean` annotation on my config file with all the manual registration stuff and had the same problem with my logs being bombarded with *"TelegramApiRequestException: Error getting updates"* errors.

After that, I just put `@Component` annotation over my bot class, removed bean creation from a config class, and it worked just fine.

My guess is that telegrambots library makes it so your bot is registered whenever Spring creates a bean out of it, and when you manually register it, then there are two instances of the bot, thus the errors.